# Create script dynamically in page Liferay

Tags: javascript, liferay

I need to create a cookie in the main page of the portal in Liferay, because I need to save some information about the users that visit the page, but I don't know if there exists any way to do it dynamically.

I know that in 'Control Panel -> Sites Page'  you can add JavaScript in the page that you want, then exist the way to do it since the code?

I'm just really lost.

Comment: You want to check for cookie if already exists before creating a new one right ???

Comment: No, I want create a script in a page that when it executes create a cookie to save information. For example, have a script in the main page that when the user visit it save information about he (referer, time, ...). But do it dinamically because I can't go to the page and put '<script>...</script>'. For this I thought if exist any way to do it like control panel but since code.

Comment: What is the problem adding the `<script>` tag in `Control Panel --> Site Page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandra, I am not able to understand your requirement clearly. Which part needs to be dynamic ?

1. For a page you can add your script i.e From Page Setting > select Page > Javascript tab where you can have your script (as suggested by Prakash)
2. If your script needs to be run for specific portlet you can add script in js/main.js for your respective portlet or Theme if it needs to be executed for all pages. (as suggested by Yanni)

Comment: What is it you are specifically looking for ?

Comment: Thanks! I wanted that the script was insert automatic but I think is not possible, I do it with the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can create a [custom-jsp hook](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-jsp). this way you 'override' a portal's jsp code. Adding a small script inside an existing code is the ideal scenario for jsp hooks.

BUT: for your case, i don't think that there is a specific portlet's page you want to alter. If you could apply this to the Theme, it would run on every portal's page, not just the MainPage. Why not create a simple portlet that runs this script, and put this portlet in the portal's Main Page.